# Going back to a previous line in a .txt file

Tags: c++, text-files

I've already read numerous articles on how to read a specific line from a .txt file, but none of them do what I need.  I'm creating a simple parser for a sort of "programming language" and I want to include a "label" system.  The thing is, though, in order to go to a specific label, I may have to go back or forwards in the text file.  How do I go to a specific line in the .txt file?  Is there a way to do this so I can return to the original line afterwards?  Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can try is random access of files to move to any position of file.

Refer to : http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/137-random-file-io/